# Response.Redirect is performing POST instead of GET

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, get, response.redirect

I have a LinkButton on my page and when it is clicked, the normal behaviour will postback to the same page (you can tell the page was POSTed by refreshing the page hitting F5 and you will get a confirm box from the browser "The page you are looking for used information that you entered. Returning to the page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?")

So in order to prevent users from resubmitting processed forms, I decided to response.redirect it to the same page.

```
void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); //redirecting back to the same page
}
```

As far as I'm concerned, a Response.Redirect should be using GET, but in this case it is using POST (after the redirect, a F5 refresh will still prompt me if I want to resubmit the form). I suspect that the Response.Redirect was not executed so I changed the url from "Default.aspx" to "HelloWorld.aspx" which is located in the same server same directory and it redirected properly. Hitting F5 now will instantly refresh the page without asking me if I want to resubmit the page.

What gives? I have other codes on my page but I doubt they caused this behaviour and they're too long to be posted here. If need be, I'll furnish it. Thank you for your time reading this.

Comment: Please post back here if you ever do find a workaround on chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What is Happening

I have noticed this issue in Chrome, but not Firefox or IE.

In fact, Chrome is performing a GET, but it is tying the POST and the GET together -- I suppose there is some optimization involved.

You can confirm this behavior by hitting <kbd>Ctrl-F12</kbd>, viewing the network tab. Note that there will be a 302 POST AND a 200 GET.

I do not understand exactly what Chrome is doing, as the debugger shows a 302 followed by a GET, yet the refresh clearly prompts about form re-submission.

## Information Conflict

There is severe misinformation regarding 302 redirects on the Internet, especially on Stack Overflow.

Historically, most browsers have converted POSTs to GETs when encountering a 302 redirect.

However, according to the standard, a POST should stay a POST, and a GET should stay a GET ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)). Despite this, most browsers continue to convert all 302's to GETs.

They probably do this because the typical browsing experience is more annoying with all the extra form re-submission dialogs. It's probably faster browsing too.

## How to Fix It

A 303 redirect is the proper way to redirect the application after a POST.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Status = "303 See Other";
Response.AddHeader("Location", "MyNewURL");
Response.End();
```

All browsers will behave consistently if you use this method, as browsers must use GET for the new URL.

**References**

- [302 Redirects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)
- [303 Redirects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303)

Comment: I just tried HTTP 303 in the latest version of Chrome and I still get the "Confirm Form Resubmission" dialog. There doesn't appear to be an elegant solution right now.

Comment: I can confirm that I get the bad behavior with 302's, and I can confirm that I get the desired behavior with 303. Can you please verify that you have removed all 302's?

Comment: I just tried it again and I get the "Confirm Form Resubmission" with 303. Flow is like this in Fiddler: HTTP POST Default.aspx --> HTTP 303 See Other Location: /Default.aspx --> HTTP Get Default.aspx. Then dialog box. I'm using Chrome Version 25.0.1364.160 m on Windows 8, maybe you're using OS X?

Comment: Chrome 25 Win 7 here. I'm completely at a loss. I experienced the same problem and fixed it with the above. I think I'll leave my answer though in case it helps others. Sorry it didn't work for you

Comment: I think the post is very helpful, you should leave it. I will investigate later on my Win 7 box.

Comment: Win 7 Ultimate SP1 with Chrome v25.0.1364.160 m (latest as of this writing). Performed 303 as the above codes and yet I'm still prompted with form re-submission confirmation dialog. As the standard dictates, 303 is the way to go for redirection particularly after a POST submission. I couldn't get the desired result as mentioned by @GeorgeWBush

Comment: Thanks for posting your results. It's truly bizarre, and I spent way too much time on this question trying to figure it out! But I learned something. :) Let's hope they fix it...

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Chrome? The [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern appears to be broken, resulting in the "Confirm Form Resubmission" dialog even if a Response.Redirect() is issued: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=21245

Second, Response.Redirect() always works like this, using Default.aspx as an example:

- Open page
- Client: HTTP GET Default.aspx
- Server: HTTP 200 Ok
- Enter form data, press submit button
- Client: HTTP POST Default.aspx
- Server: HTTP 302 Redirect to Default.aspx
- Client: HTTP GET Default.aspx

I created a sample ASP.NET app with a form, then added a LinkButton with an event handler that calls `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)`, which by the way is preferred over something like `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")` because it uses relative paths for the calling page and works in development and deployed environments.

In IE, after entering data into the form and pressing Submit, then pressing F5, I didn't get a "Confirm Form Resubmission" dialog. Same with Firefox; no dialog. But in Chrome, I did receive the warning. My only conclusion is that you might be hitting the Chrome issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Chrome. After reading this, I tried it on IE and Firefox, no form re-submission dialog. An interesting fact, not that it matters anyway: you will only get the form re-submission confirmation dialog if you are directed back to the same page with the exact same set of querystrings in the exact same order from the one you're originally from. If you're currently on Default.aspx and redirected to Default.aspx?id=101, you won't be getting the dialog. Even if you're currently on Default.aspx?id=101&name=abc and redirected to Default.aspx?name=abc&id=101, you won't be getting the dialog.